# Cannot emulate Expo project

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

Every time I try to emulate Expo project, only real device emulation works.

> the experience you requested requires a newer version of the expo
>   client app

[image: the experience you requested requires a newer version of the expo client app]

How do I update expo client software that sets up iOS / Android emulator bundling?

Comment: Have you tried to update the expo client app using either the ios app store or the google play store? Normally thats how you update the client

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get iOS emulator working, Emulator Expo App should be updated. I followed an instruction by raphael4ndrade (https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1595):
iOS Emulator / Hardware / Erase All Content and Settings and then pressed 'Run on iOS Simulator' in Expo localhost once again and the RN project finally bundled.